# python: give strings in an array an integer value

Tags: python, arrays, type-conversion

So I'm working on a question where I get an array of random lenght with 4 different strings 'a', 'b','c','d' wich are also random. So for example:

```
s = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c'] or s = ['d', 'b']
```

I'm looking for a way to give each of these strings exact one integer value of my choice so i can make a sum out of these. Like 'a' gets the value 1, 'b' gets -1 for example.
I was looking for a solution but bc I'm new to python and programming I've been struggling with it.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you make a dictionary

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': -1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

then you can use

```
[d[c] for c in s]
```

to transform the list to a list of the numbers.